# AttributeError at /content/create/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python, django

Я пытаюсь составить формсет: мне нужно, чтобы при попадании на страницу с этим обработчиком я мог создать статью и тут же добавить в неё контент

views.py

```
class ContentCreateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    model = None
    obj = None
    template_name = 'content/create.html'

    def get_model(self, model_name):
        if model_name in ['text', 'video', 'image', 'file']:
            return apps.get_model(app_label='content',
                                  model_name=model_name)
        return None

    def get_form(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
        Form = modelform_factory(model, exclude=['title','created',])
        return Form(*args, **kwargs)

    def dispatch(self, request, model_name=None, article_id=None, id=None):
        if article_id:
            self.article = get_object_or_404(Article,
                                       id=article_id,)
        if model_name:
            self.model = self.get_model(model_name)
        if id:
            self.obj = get_object_or_404(self.model,
                                         id=id)
        return super(ContentCreateView,self).dispatch(request, model_name, id)

    def get(self, request, model_name, id=None):
        form = self.get_form(self.model, instance=self.obj)
        return self.render_to_response({'form': form,
                                        'object': self.obj})

    def post(self, request, model_name, id=None):
        form = self.get_form(self.model,instance=self.obj,data=request.POST,files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj.save()
            if not id:
                Content.objects.create(article=self.article,
                                       item=obj)
            return redirect('content/detail.html', self.article.id)

        return self.render_to_response({'form': form,
                                        'object': self.obj})
```

Но получаю ошибку. В чём проблема, и что ещё в теории неправильно в моём коде?

Comment: А какие параметры передаются при попадании на эту страницу при запросе `POST`? Ошибка говорит о том, что передаются какие-то лишние параметры, не описанные в функции `post`, если я правильно понимаю.

Comment: @CrazyElf перезапустил локалхост, теперь вместо post() пишет get(). Ввести ничего не успеваю, в urls.py 
`path('create/', views.ContentCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),` так что без понятия

Comment: `super(ContentCreateView, self).dispatch(request, article_id, model_name, id)` проблема тут. dispatch внутри  перенаправляет вызов (со всеми параметрами) методу в зависимости от http метода. в вашем случае `get(self, request, model_name, id=None)`, у которого нет `article_id`

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA убрал article_id, теперь ошибка `AttributeError at /content/create/
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__' `